# Get Parameters Type and no. of parameters for a function in Visual Studio Editor (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

After writing the name and opening and closing parentheses (brackets) of a function in C#, is there any way to get the types and number of parameters of the function, *without deleting the opening parenthesis*?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Place the cursor between the parentheses and press Ctrl-Shift-Space.

Comment: +1 ... tiny little trick to noticeably improve daily work with the IDE.

Comment: Was trying to get an answer to this one. +1

Answer (score 1):

I used to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> all the time but it's not working anymore.
It does show the parameter list when I delete the opening bracket though.

Turns our it is my wireless keyboard not allowing more then 2 keys to be pressed at once, works fine if I used the windows virtual keyboard.